# How to fix RN app resetting on change of StateContext using dispatcher in combination with react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux, react-context

At my job we are creating a RN app with Expo and we currently use react-navigation for our routing needs. We are currently trying to migrate over to using react-native-router-flux, as it allows for uriPrefix => app Deep Linking out of box and seems like an overall better solution for our company needs. We have looked at the Expo example code in the react-native-router-flux repo and followed it accordingly.

The issue we are running into is anytime global state changes (we are combining Context API and React Hooks to create a global StateProvider that sits above App.js. See: https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c) using a dispatcher action, the entire app resets itself and shoots you back to the initial home screen. Prior to this, we were using npm reactn to manage a global state of sorts, as we wanted to try and avoid the heavy / tedious setup of redux. Has anyone else run into an issue like this where every time global state changes, the entire app refreshes itself (rather than doing a vDOM comparison and rerendering only what has changed). We don't see this behavior when using react-navigation for routing.

```
  const defaultReducer = new Reducer(params);
  return (state, action) => {
    console.log(`reducer: ${action.type} ${action.routeName}`);
    return defaultReducer(state, action);
  };
};

const stateHandler = (prevState, newState, action) => {
  console.log('onStateChange: ACTION:', action);
};

const getSceneStyle = () => ({
  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  shadowOpacity: 1,
  shadowRadius: 3,
});

const drawerImg = () => {
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('../../assets/images/icon-img.png')}
      style={{
        height: 63,
        width: 63,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
      }}
    />
  );
};

// on Android, the URI prefix typically contains a host in addition to scheme
const prefix = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'myApp://myApp/' : 'myApp://';

const transitionConfig = () => ({
  screenInterpolator: StackViewStyleInterpolator.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
});

export const AppNavigator = React.forwardRef(() => (
  <Router
    createReducer={reducerCreate}
    onStateChange={stateHandler}
    getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle}
    uriPrefix={prefix}
  >
    <Overlay key="overlay">
      <Modal key="modal" hideNavBar transitionConfig={transitionConfig}>
        <Lightbox key="lightbox">
          <Stack
            key="root"
            hideNavBar
            titleStyle={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
            navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: themeColor }}
          >
            <Drawer
              hideNavBar
              key="drawer"
              onExit={() => {
                console.log('Drawer closed');
              }}
              onEnter={() => {
                console.log('Drawer opened');
              }}
              // drawerImage={drawerImg}
              contentComponent={DrawerContent}
              drawerWidth={300}
            >
              <Scene hideNavBar>
                <Tabs key="tabbar" swipeEnabled>
                  <Scene
                    initial
                    key={`homeStack`}
                    title={`Home`}
                    icon={({ focused }) => (
                      <CustomIcon name="home" size={24} focused={focused} />
                    )}
                  >
                    <Scene key={`homeScreen`} component={HomeScreen} />
                  </Scene>
                  <Scene
                    key={`communityStack`}
                    title={`Communities`}
                    icon={({ focused }) => (
                      <CustomIcon name={`group`} size={24} focused={focused} />
                    )}
                  >
                    <Scene key={`communityList`} component={CommunityList} />
                    <Scene key={`communityFeed`} component={CommunityFeed} />
                  </Scene>
                  <Scene
                    key={`notificationStack`}
                    title={`Notifications`}
                    icon={({ focused }) => (
                      <CustomIcon
                        name={`notifications`}
                        size={24}
                        focused={focused}
                      />
                    )}
                  >
                    <Scene
                      key="notifications"
                      // component={Test}
                      component={NotificationsScreen}
                    />
                  </Scene>
                  <Scene
                    key={`profileStack`}
                    title={`Profile`}
                    icon={({ focused }) => (
                      <CustomIcon name={`profile`} size={20} focused={focused} />
                    )}
                  >
                    <Scene key="profile" component={OwnProfileScreen} />
                  </Scene>
                </Tabs>
              </Scene>
            </Drawer>
          </Stack>
        </Lightbox>
      </Modal>
    </Overlay>
  </Router>
));


// this is what the dispatcher action looks like in componentDidMount of one of the components. 

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    console.log(`mounting homescreen.js`);

    // this causes infinite refresh
    const [_, dispatch] = this.context;

    const storedKeys = await _getAllStoredKeys();
    if (!storedKeys.find(key => key === `currentUser`)) {
      console.log(`no currentUser in cache, redirecting to login`);
    } else {
      var res = await _getStoredItem(`currentUser`);
      dispatch({ type: SET_USER, setUser: res });
    }
  };
```

When pressing on a tab to navigate to a different screen from the homeStack screen (initial route), I expect the screen to be rendered and set properly, what actually happens is the screen is mounted (confirmed via console.log() in componentDidMount()) and then it shoots user back to initial Scene of homeStack.

Answer (score 0):

We found that the most recent beta version of router-flux (v4.1.0-beta.x) doesn't seem to play nicely with redux (or any other kind of state-management) and have decided to go down a different route for universal links and deep-linking by looking at what this engineer did: https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-react-native-web-app-a-happy-struggle-aea7906f4903